# PromQL : compare metric value with its label's value

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

I have this metric : `my_metric{expected_value="123"} 123`

Using Prometheus, how can create an alert that triggers when the value differs from the label `expected_value`'s value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Labels are not supposed to be used in this way, and there are no ways of combination labels and metric values.

Best course of action in this case would be to split your metric into two metrics:

```
my_metric 123
my_metric_expected_value 123
```

And introduce alerting rule based on expression:

```
my_metric != my_metric_expected_value
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll keep the question open for a day or two in hope someone has others thoughs to share ;)

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus doesn't allow comparing label value with metric value as said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76582988/274937). If you still want to do this, then try the following query in [Prometheus-like alternative system I work on](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/):

```
label_value(my_metric, "expected_value") != my_metric
```

It uses [label_value](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_value) function for extracting numeric label value from the `expected_value` label at `my_metric` metric.